# Is nth click possible?

Tags: html, css, onclick

I have a website with a button that I want to trigger an action the second time it is clicked. Ideally, it would happen every other click, but I'd be ok with it just occurring once on the second click. Think of it like double-clicking a desktop folder.

How do I accomplish this and is it possible with just HTML + CSS?

Comment: If you want a double click, then the `'dblclick'` event will do what you want.

Comment: Do you want an action on every second click, or do you want an action on every double-click? The two have important differences. As for just HTML + CSS: you won’t be able to accomplish this in general without JavaScript without hacks.

Comment: (Also, context might help provide better solutions to the overall problem. Have you thought about accessibility for those who don’t use a mouse? How about mobile devices, which have a different set of expected gestures?)